# query group by with order by

Tags: php, sql, symfony

i need to create query with group by and order by, and i dont know how to do it.

query should return one record for the newest date for existing device_serial_number. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkwNf.png)

so i would to get id 591 nad 592

solution can be in sql or the best way it will be in symfony, through query builder etc.

Comment: Based on your explanation, you can not receive 591 and 592, it would be 590 and 592. The entry with ID 590 is newer than 591 by the created_at value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want.

**First Way**
The oldest way to select first, best, worst, whatever within a group is with a correlated subquery:

```
Select * from mytable outer
Where created_at = (
    Select max(created_at)
    from mytable inner
    Where inner.device_serial_number = outer.device_serial_number
)
```

**Second Way**
Use a subselect to find earliest dates for all devices, them join back to the original table to filter:

```
Select a.*
From mytable a Inner Join
     (Select device_serial_number, max(created_at) as latedate
       From mytable b
       Group By device_serial_number
      ) b
      On a.device_serial_number=b.device_serial_number
       And a.created_at=b.latedate
```

**Third way**
Use a window function to rank order all the dates and then pick the number one ranking.

```
Select * From (
    Select *
        , rank() Over (Partition By device_serial_number Order by created_at desc) as myrank
    From mytable
)
Where myrank=1
```

Notice that while these 3 solutions use different aspects of SQL, they all have a common analytical approach.  They are all two step processes whose first (inner) part involves finding the most recent created_at date for each device_serial_number and then reapplying that result back to the original table in the second (outer) part.